# Button intended just for MapView tab shows up on both tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview

I've got a 2-tabbed activity, one tab containing an info screen (it's id in the code below is 'targetLayout') with some TextViews and the other tab containing a MapView. Using the layout, I'm trying to add a button that shows just on the MapView tab screen, but it's showing up on both. The odd thing is, if I alter the layout such that the button is on just the info tab, that works. I have to be missing something, but it's not apparent what.

Here's the layout that results in the button showing up on both:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/targetLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetPositionLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Target Position"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetPosition"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetPositionLabel"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Waiting"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetRangeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetPosition"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Range(M):"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetAzimuthLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetRangeLabel"
                    android:text="Azimuth(Deg):"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetElevationLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetAzimuthLabel"
                    android:text="Elevation(Deg):"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetTimeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetElevationLabel"
                    android:text="Time lased:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewGPSAccuracy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetTimeLabel"
                    android:text="GPS Accuracy When Lased:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewYourPositionLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGPSAccuracy"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Your Position"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewYourPosition"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewYourPositionLabel"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Waiting for GPS Fix"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewGPSStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewYourPosition"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="GPS Status: Initializing" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewGPSInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewGPSStatus"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewGPSStatus"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mapview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:apiKey="<my key is in here>"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:enabled="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/googlemaps_select_location"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Select" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

And here's the layout that puts the button on just the info tab. The only thing different is that the button is now in the info tab's RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/targetLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetPositionLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Target Position"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetPosition"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetPositionLabel"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Waiting"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetRangeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetPosition"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Range(M):"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetAzimuthLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetRangeLabel"
                    android:text="Azimuth(Deg):"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetElevationLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetAzimuthLabel"
                    android:text="Elevation(Deg):"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTargetTimeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetElevationLabel"
                    android:text="Time lased:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewGPSAccuracy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTargetTimeLabel"
                    android:text="GPS Accuracy When Lased:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewYourPositionLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGPSAccuracy"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Your Position"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewYourPosition"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewYourPositionLabel"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Waiting for GPS Fix"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewGPSStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewYourPosition"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="GPS Status: Initializing" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewGPSInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewGPSStatus"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewGPSStatus"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/googlemaps_select_location"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Select" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mapview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:apiKey="my key is in here"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:enabled="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tracked down the solution. In the code for my activity, I was populating the MapView tab using the MapView view, id 'mapview' in the layout code in my original question. Populating the tab using the RelativeLayout that contains the MapView view, id 'mainlayout', made it work correctly. I wrote the original code basing it on an example I found on the net, and it works fine until you start trying to embellish it like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code  shows your tabs on the screen?

Comment: Yes, the application activity shows two tabs, one labeled "Target" and one labeled "Map".

Answer (score 0):

I've always had my separate tab views in different files.

MainLayout.xml - Contains the tab host and a Frame Layout.

Tab1.xml - Contains tab 1's layout

Tab2.xml - Contains tab 2's layout

On the tab select function in the main activity, you check to see which tab was selected and place that xml file into the frame layout of the MainLaout.xml. Check the android tab sample project for details.